# cant find start-all.sh in hadoop installation

Tags: hadoop, installation, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to setup hadoop on my local machine and was following [this](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/). I have setup hadoop home also

This is the command I am trying to run now

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ /usr/local/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh
```

And this is the error I get

```
-su: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh: No such file or directory
```

This is what I added to my $HOME/.bashrc file

```
# Set Hadoop-related environment variables
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop

# Set JAVA_HOME (we will also configure JAVA_HOME directly for Hadoop later on)
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

# Some convenient aliases and functions for running Hadoop-related commands
unalias fs &> /dev/null
alias fs="hadoop fs"
unalias hls &> /dev/null
alias hls="fs -ls"

# If you have LZO compression enabled in your Hadoop cluster and
# compress job outputs with LZOP (not covered in this tutorial):
# Conveniently inspect an LZOP compressed file from the command
# line; run via:
#
# $ lzohead /hdfs/path/to/lzop/compressed/file.lzo
#
# Requires installed 'lzop' command.
#
lzohead () {
    hadoop fs -cat $1 | lzop -dc | head -1000 | less
}

# Add Hadoop bin/ directory to PATH
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

**EDIT After trying the solution given by mahendra I am getting the following output**

`This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-mmt-HP-ProBook-430-G3.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-mmt-HP-ProBook-430-G3.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-mmt-HP-ProBook-430-G3.out
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-mmt-HP-ProBook-430-G3.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-mmt-HP-ProBook-430-G3.out`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to run :

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-all.sh
```

Since *start-all.sh* and *stop-all.sh* located in `sbin` directory while *hadoop* binary file is located in `bin` directory.

Also updated your `.bashrc` for:

> export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:**$HADOOP_HOME/sbin**

so that you can directly access `start-all.sh`

Comment: Hi, its  been long since I aksed this question. your above command works and is giving the output I have posted in the edit part. Is that the correct output?

Comment: Refer accepted answer of [how-to-check-if-hadoop-daemons-are-running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555965/how-to-check-if-hadoop-daemons-are-running). In local mode you can also check java processes using  `$JAVA_HOME/bin/jps` command